# Is there a way to find out why an email address is 'on hold'?

Tags: bounce

I'm currently going through our system and there is a lot of emails that have been put on hold, is there a way to find out or is there a list somewhere on the database as to why each one is specifically on hold  (i.e. email is not active or security issues)? I'm currently having to go through one by one which is necessary but time consuming.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `I'm currently having to go through one by one which is necessary but time consuming.` Is there a field you check on each contact which explains the reason for email on hold?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you want the "Bounce Report".  Click on **Reports menu » Mailing Reports**, select **Bounce Report**.  In "Columns", check the "Bounce Reason" checkbox, and ideally "Bounce Type" as well.